# Slow speed when return statement

Tags: python, performance, return, cython

I have this cython code just for testing:

```
cimport cython

cpdef loop(int k):
    return real_loop(k)

@cython.cdivision
cdef real_loop(int k):
    cdef int i
    cdef float a
    for i in xrange(k):
        a = i
        a = a**2 / (a + 1)
    return a
```

And I test speed diffence between this cython code and the same code in pure python with a script like that:

```
import mymodule

print(mymodule.loop(100000))
```

I get 80times faster. But if I remove the two return statement in cython code , I get 800-900times faster. Why ?

Another things is if I run this code ( with return ) on my old ACER Aspire ONE notebook I get 700times faster and on a new desktop i7 PC at home , 80times faster.

Somebody know why ?

Comment: It's hard to say -- I wonder if the compiler would be smart enough to see that `real_loop` doesn't update any globals, and it doesn't change any of the arguments, so it can be turned into a no-op.

Comment: Did you try to `diff` the two generated C files to see the differences? Anyway, maybe it's because cython sees that the functions without `return` are useless and does loop at all.

Comment: @Bakuriu yes , it's what I think. probably don't do the loop at all. I don't know how but yesterday when I try different manner to code it I get sometime ridiculous performance like 12 000 times faster.

Comment: That's simply too much. It means the compiler replaced the whole loop to a single no-op. You should see this if the time taken doesn't change with the input size.

Comment: You probably have different compilers on those systems. On my Corei5 laptop with gcc4.7.2, mymodule.loop(N) always takes ~120 nanoseconds, no matter how large the N is, i.e. it skips the loop.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisGallant have you tried the answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested you problem with the following code:

```
#cython: wraparound=False
#cython: boundscheck=False
#cython: cdivision=True
#cython: nonecheck=False
#cython: profile=False

def loop(int k):
 return real_loop(k)

def loop2(int k):
 cdef float a
 real_loop2(k, &a)
 return a

def loop3(int k):
    real_loop3(k)
    return None

def loop4(int k):
    return real_loop4(k)

def loop5(int k):
 cdef float a
 real_loop5(k, &a)
 return a

cdef float real_loop(int k):
    cdef int i
    cdef float a
    a = 0.
    for i in range(k):
        a += a**2 / (a + 1)
    return a

cdef void real_loop2(int k, float *a):
    cdef int i
    a[0] = 0.
    for i in range(k):
        a[0] += a[0]**2 / (a[0] + 1)

cdef void real_loop3(int k):
    cdef int i
    cdef float a
    a = 0.
    for i in range(k):
        a += a**2 / (a + 1)

cdef float real_loop4(int k):
    cdef int i
    cdef float a
    a = 0.
    for i in range(k):
        a += a*a / (a + 1)
    return a

cdef void real_loop5(int k, float *a):
    cdef int i
    a[0] = 0.
    for i in range(k):
        a[0] += a[0]*a[0] / (a[0] + 1)
```

where `real_loop()` is close to your function, with a modified formula for `a` since the original one seemed strange.

Function `real_loop2()` is not returning any value, just updating `a` by reference.

Function `real_loop3()` is not returning any value.

Checking the generated `C` code for `real_loop3()` one can see that the loop is there, and the code is called... but I had the same conclusion as @dmytro, changing `k` won't change the timing significantly... so there must be a point that I am missing here.

From the timings below we can say that `return` is not the bottleneck since `real_loop2()` and `real_loop5()` have do not return any value, and their performance is the same as `real_loop()` and `real_loop4()`, respectively.

```
In [2]: timeit _stack.loop(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop

In [3]: timeit _stack.loop2(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 ms per loop

In [4]: timeit _stack.loop3(100000)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 78.5 ns per loop

In [5]: timeit _stack.loop4(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 913 µs per loop

In [6]: timeit _stack.loop5(100000)
1000 loops, best of 3: 979 µs per loop
```

Note the ~2X speed-up changing `a**2` by `a*a`, since `a**2` requires a function call `powf()` inside the loop.